# Check if a Windows Service exists with Python

Tags: python, windows-services

I wrote a program in python that interacts with a Windows service. However, before doing it, I need check if the service is installed.

I'm using the following code to get the service. But if it not exists, I receive error.

```
win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus('myservice')
```

**This is the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win32serviceutil.pyc", line 835, in SvcRun
  File "main.py", line 54, in SvcDoRun
  File "main.py", line 103, in main
  File "main.py", line 57, in start_service
  File "main.pyc", line 495, in QueryServiceStatus
  File "main.pyc", line 80, in SmartOpenService
error: (1060, 'GetServiceKeyName', 'The specified service does not exist as an installed service')
```

Is there any way I can check it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like a Try-Except block would be the easiest solution:

```
try: 
    win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus('myservice')
except:
    print "Windows service NOT installed"
else:
    print "Windows service installed"
```

Comment: @ECC, davmat's answer is perfectly elegant and Pythonic and it answers your question, as far as I can tell. If you don't think so, perhaps you should reformulate your question to tell more specifically what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

It can be done using [`psutil` 4.2.0 or newer](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#windows-services):

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import psutil

def get_service(name):
    service = None
    try:
        service = psutil.win_service_get(name)
        service = service.as_dict()
    except Exception as ex:
        # raise psutil.NoSuchProcess if no service with such name exists
        print(str(ex))

    return service

service = get_service('LanmanServer')

if service:
    print("Service found: ", service)
else:
    print("Service not found")

if service and service['status'] == 'running':
    print("Service is running")
else: 
    print("Service is not running")
```